# My Excel workbook has multiple, unknown encodings, so equality tests fail

Tags: excel, unicode, vlookup

I've accumulated a lot of Japanese Kanji data over the years, and have just assembled a workbook of some interesting lists. I was hoping to use `VLOOKUP` to join some of them but that failed because while two kanji look the same, they are, I guess, encoded differently so they don't match exactly (`range_lookup = FALSE` gives `#N/A` when it should return a value, using `TRUE` gives a reasonable but useless value).

I just solved the problem - I pasted two identical but non-matching characters into Notepad, saved it as UTF-8, then pasted them back where they came from and now `VLOOKUP` works as expected.

If anyone knows why Notepad is so smart and Excel so dumb, please let me know. I know Japan had its own encoding schemes way before unicode, but don't they show up as ??? in Notepad? I guess the encodings were 'close enough' so that Notepad (and Excel) would display them as identical characters. Am I close? Also, is there a workbook function that "normalizes" these encoding cousins to a default for comparisons?

Comment: Thanks @Jasper de Vries. My Q/A was worse than I thought - the problem was actually non breaking spaces - a beginner's mistake! I assumed the issue was unicode because kanji were involved. In my tests I had carefully copy/pasted just the character. If I had just clicked I would have seen the space. =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(D1,CHAR(160),CHAR(32))) does the trick. At the core, the problem was my original sources weren't really the downloaded spreadsheets. They had probably been compiled from web sites and web sites are notorious for using nonbreaking spaces. I hope my pathetic story helps others.

Comment: This whole thing may belong in "super user." I'd like to say that I'm too modest to call myself "super", but somehow, I just didn't see the site in the drop down list. Is this a common problem that needs fixing?